# How to set "charset=utf-8" in GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType(contentType)

Tags: java, web, amazon-s3, http-headers

How  to set "charset=utf-8" in

`GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType(contentType)`

I tried so (it did not work):

```
String contentType = "charset=utf-8";

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest
generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(str,
str2); generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType(contentType);
```

contentType = ?

Comment: You might need to specify the content type first and follow it with the charset. Such as `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

mb try `application/octet-stream`